# Django gunicorn service not working, Got error failed at step EXEC spawning {PATH}/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup a django project in local machine with gunicorn, nginx.

I did setup gunicorn `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` by following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Sharing `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` file configuration below.

---

```
Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target
```

[Service]
User=bm
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/bm/www/html/erp
ExecStart=/home/bm/www/html/erp/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          erp.erp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

When i am trying to run `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` . It gives the error response `gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/bm/www/html/erp/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory`. As per tutorial i am not getting any steps to create `gunicorn` file on `erp/env/bin` folder. Do I need to create a gunicorn file on bin folder Or need any other configuration to fix this issue?

I am sharing my full error message below. please help if anyone have any idea?

```
bm@Lenovo:~/www/html/erp/erp$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-04-14 21:12:06 IST; 52min ago
Main PID: 5932 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Apr 14 21:12:06 Lenovo systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Apr 14 21:12:06 Lenovo systemd[5932]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Apr 14 21:12:06 Lenovo systemd[5932]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/bm/www/html/erp/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
Apr 14 21:12:06 Lenovo systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 14 21:12:06 Lenovo systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 14 21:12:30 Lenovo systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:10: Executable path is not absolute: gunicorn            --access-logfile -            --workers 3            --bind uni
Apr 14 21:15:08 Lenovo systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:10: Executable path is not absolute: gunicorn            --access-logfile -            --workers 3            --bind uni
lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

Comment: the tutorial doesn't but the project expects the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Actually gunicorn was not installed properly on my virtual environment so gunicorn file  was not created.